# Matplotlib animation not working as expected

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am working on animating the path of a ball using matplotlib in python and MovieWriter to animate the path frame by frame. I want the path of the ball to have its line drawn over the course of a 100 frames, for the end result looking like the GOLDEN (only line my animation deals with) line [image: in this image]. However I end up getting an irregularly shifting line in my animation mp4 video. I can't post the video but a snapshot of it looks like [image: this]. This line moves the end away from the origin around the plot, but doesn't form a coherent line that is depicted in the first image. What am I doing wrong? My code is below

```html
FFMpegWriter = manimation.writers['ffmpeg']
metadata = dict(title='Movie Test', artist='Matplotlib',
                    comment='Movie support!')
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=15, metadata=metadata)

import glob

#plt figure
fig = plt.figure()

#get specific file with data
fn = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\STATS_basketball_tracking\anon\train\specificfile")

#plot image of the court
img = plt.imread(r"C:\Users\Admin\Pictures\Capture4.png ")
plt.imshow(img, zorder=0, extent=[0, 47, 0, 50])



tups = bball.stats_basketball.read_tuples(fn) 
positions = bball.stats_basketball.get_positions(tups)
goals = bball.stats_basketball.get_goals(tups)
ball = positions[0]

#initial x and y coordinate (col 0= x-coordinates col 1= y-coordinates)
x0 = ball[0,0]
y0 = ball[0,1]
lball, = plt.plot([x0], [y0], color="goldenrod")
     
with writer.saving(fig, "writer_test.mp4", 100):
    for i in range(100):
        for row in ball[:,0]:
            for row1 in ball[:,1]:
                x0 = [int(row),0]
                y0 = [int(row1),1]
                lball.set_data(x0, y0)
                fig.canvas.draw()
                writer.grab_frame()
```

Comment: It's really hard to say from your code, as we don't know how your data looks like. Could you cook this down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some 'fake data'? I'm guessing that you only plot one point at a time, while you would rather want to collect the data from each file and 'grow' a line out of them. Also, I think you shouldn't be calling `plt.plot` for each frame, but instead adjust the line (`lball`) at each iteration.

Comment: @ThomasKühn thanks for your advice! i added some comments in the code after condensing it a bit to help you all out a little bit. the data is a 2 column matrix with the first column having rows of x coordinates of the basketball's path and the second one the same but with y coordinates. how would i adjust the line at each iteration? is set_data not the right thing? thank you!

Comment: I think your problem is in the way you update your data. Instead of `x0 = [int(row),0]`, try `x0.append(int(row))` and similarly for `y0`. Otherwise you will always just have a line between two points.